# Unable to solve Largest Contentful Paint element

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Recently I have developed an application on nextjs 14 and published this app to live server. After that, to improve my page performance i was testing my pages on [PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/). And found our one of my section is getting red flag with "Largest Contentful Paint element" on a image. It is top section of my webpage (its a landing page). I have searched and applied lots of solution online, but couldn't resolve this issue. Here is my full component:

return (
<>

```
  <main className='bg-black text-white'>
    <script
      type="application/ld+json"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonLd) }}
    />

    <section className='home-banner-wrapper'>
      <div className='basis-[45%] flex flex-col items-start'>
        {data?.top_title && (
          <h1 className='mb-5 text-[28px] lg:text-[52px] leading-[40px] lg:leading-[66px] font-extrabold'>
            {data.top_title}
          </h1>
        )}

        {data?.top_subtitle && (
          <p className='mb-[60px] text-xl font-light leading-8 lg:leading-9'>
            {data.top_subtitle}
          </p>
        )}

        {data?.cta_link && (
          <p className='flex m-0 justify-center items-center'>
          <Link
            href={data.cta_link}
            className='learn-more-btn'
          >
            Learn More
            <Image
              src='/images/arrow-circle-right.svg'
              width={24}
              height={25}
              alt="Arrow Icon"
              priority={true}
            />
          </Link>
          </p>
        )}
      </div>

      {data?.banner_image && (
        <div className='-mt-[120px] basis-[55%] flex items-stretch'>
          <Image
            src={data.banner_image}
            className='!w-[748px] lg:min-h-[500px]'
            width={748}
            height={500}
            alt="Top Banner"
            priority={true}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </section>


    <section className='benefit-list-wrapper'>
      {data?.benefit_list
        && data.benefit_list.map((item, index) =>
      {
        return (
          <div key={index} className='flex-1'>
            <p className='benefit-list-item'>
              {item?.be_icon && (
                <Image
                  className='mb-0.5'
                  src={item.be_icon}
                  width={37}
                  height={38}
                  alt={""}
                />
              )} <span className='pl-1'>{item.be_title}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </section>


    <section className='px-5 2xl:px-0 pt-[88px] mx-auto lg:w-auto'>
      {data?.functionality_title && (
        <h1 className='text-2xl lg:text-4xl !leading-50 text-center font-semibold'>
          {data.functionality_title}
        </h1>
      )}

      {data?.functionality_subtitle && (
        <>
          <div className='max-w-[290px] bg-secondary h-0.5 mx-auto lg:mt-5'></div>
          <p className='text-lg lg:text-[20px] leading-[32px] pt-5 lg:pt-[28px] text-center'>
            {data.functionality_subtitle}
          </p>
        </>
      )}

      <div className='max-w-[1320px] mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center lg:flex-row lg:justify-between mt-[80px] lg:mt-[50px] lg:pb-[70px]'>
        <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row lg:flex-col md:justify-between gap-y-8 basis-[26%] lg:pt-5 lg:pr-[15px] items-center'>
          {data?.functionality_left
            && data.functionality_left.map((item, index) =>
          {
            return (
              <div
                className={'flex flex-col items-center min-w-[240px] lg:items-end min-h-[160px]' + (
                  index == 1 ? " lg:mr-[50px] mt-[7px]" : index == 2 ? " pt-2" : ""
                )}
                key={index}
              >
                {item?.icon && (
                  <Image
                    src={item.icon}
                    width={40}
                    height={60}
                    alt={item.title || ""}
                  />
                )}

                <h1 className='text-2xl lg:text-[28px] leading-[28px] font-semibold mt-2.5'>{item.title}</h1>
                <p className='text-[15px] leading-[28px] font-normal mt-2.5'>{item.subtitle}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>

        <div className='basis-[48%] flex my-10 lg:my-0 lg:items-center justify-center'>
          {data?.image && (
            <Image
              className='max-w-[unset] lg:-mt-[70px] w-[283px] h-[215px] lg:w-[515px] lg:h-[391px]'
              src={data.image}
              width={515}
              height={390}
              alt={data?.functionality_title || ""}
            />
          )}
        </div>

        <div className='md:flex md:flex-row md:justify-between flex flex-col lg:flex-col gap-y-9 basis-[26%] lg:pt-5 lg:pr-[15px]'>
          {data?.functionality_right
            && data.functionality_right.map((item, index) =>
          {
            return (
              <div
                className={'flex flex-col text-center lg:text-left items-center lg:items-start min-h-[164px]' + (
                  index == 1 ? " lg:ml-[20px]" : ""
                )}
                key={index}
              >
                {item?.icon && (
                  <Image
                    src={item.icon}
                    width={40}
                    height={60}
                    alt={item.title || ""}
                  />
                )}

                <h1 className={'text-2xl lg:text-[28px] leading-[28px] font-semibold mt-2.5' + (
                  index == 2 ? " w-[328px]" : ""
                )}>{item.title}</h1>
                <p className={'text-[15px] leading-[28px] font-normal mt-2.5' + (
                  index == 1 ? " w-[311px]" : ""
                )}>{item.subtitle}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <section className='px-5 2xl:px-0 pt-[60px] pb-0 lg:pb-[70px] max-w-[1237px] mx-auto'>
      {data?.video_title && (
        <h1 className='text-2xl font-semibold lg:text-4xl text-center lg:!leading-50'>
          {data.video_title}
        </h1>
      )}

      <div className='max-w-[290px] bg-secondary h-0.5 mx-auto mt-5'></div>

      {data?.video_subtitle && (
        <p className='sm:text-xl text-[16px] pt-[30px] max-w-[903px] mx-auto text-center !leading-1.6'>
          {data.video_subtitle}
        </p>
      )}

      {data?.video_subtitle_last && (
        <p className='sm:text-xl text-[16px] pt-[30px] max-w-[903px] mx-auto text-center !leading-1.6'>
          {data.video_subtitle_last}
        </p>
      )}

      {data?.youtube_video_id && (
        <VideoPlayer
          divClass="pt-[73px] relative pb-[50%] mt-10 max-w-[1188px] mx-auto"
          videoId={data.youtube_video_id}
          videoTitle={data?.video_title || ""}
        />
      )}
    </section>


    <section className='px-5 2xl:px-0 pt-[40px] pb-0 lg:pb-[140px]'>
      {data?.why_title && (
        <h1 className='text-2xl font-semibold lg:text-4xl text-center !leading-50'>
          {data.why_title}
        </h1>
      )}

      {data?.why_subtitle && (
        <>
          <div className='max-w-[280px] bg-secondary h-0.5 mx-auto mt-5'></div>
          <p className='text-xl pt-[30px] max-w-[883px] mx-auto text-center text-[16px] leading-8'>
            {data.why_subtitle}
          </p>
        </>
      )}

      <div className='mt-[50px] grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-y-10 lg:gap-y-[65px] lg:gap-x-[117px] max-w-[1458px] mx-auto'>
        {data?.list
          && data.list.map((item, index) =>
        {
          return (
            <div className='text-center basis-1/3 p-5 max-w-[408px] mx-auto' key={index}>
              {item?.icon && (
                <Image
                  src={item.icon}
                  width={60}
                  height={60}
                  alt={item.title || ""}
                  className='mx-auto mb-[14px]'
                />
              )}

              {item.title && (
                <h1 className='text-2xl lg:text-[28px] mb-4 font-semibold'>{item.title}</h1>
              )}

              {item.subtitle && (
                <p className='text-sm lg:text-base font-normal leading-[26px]'>{item.subtitle}</p>
              )}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </section>


    <FaqList
      faqList={data?.faq_list || []}
      id="home-page-faq"
    />


    <JoinNow />
  </main>
</>
```

)

And here is the report from pagespeed insights

https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-nextsono-com/3pv1cjwgw5?form_factor=mobile

Can anyone help me out with this problem? I am getting same problem on other pages as well.

Comment: You could try loading an even more smaller dimension (360px x 360px)  image for mobile screens + ensuring it is in webp format to reduce file size

Answer (score 1):

To improve Image output:
Use "Picture" tag

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width:699px)" srcSet="https://res.cloudinary.com/di7j408eq/image/upload/v1685516535/outdoor-living-slider_1_nsnsnr.webp" type="image/webp" /> // for tab media size
  <source media="(max-width:640px)" srcSet="https://res.cloudinary.com/di7j408eq/image/upload/v1685516535/outdoor-living-slider_1_nsnsnr.webp" type="image/webp" /> // for mobile media size
  <Image
    src="https://res.cloudinary.com/di7j408eq/image/upload/v1685516535/outdoor-living-slider_1_nsnsnr.webp"
    width={500}
    height={500}
    alt="calgary landscaping"
    quality={100}
    priority="low"
    loading="lazy"
  />
</picture>
```

Keep priority="low" & loading="lazy".

If the image is from the first fold then keep its priority="high" & loading="eager".

Must use webp images and if you have SVG then add the package 'react-svg' and use it for better output.

**Also suggested is using the Next.js dynamic import if not yet used.
Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#nextdynamic**

Ref: [how can i fix largest contentful paint issue in next js image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78039605/how-can-i-fix-largest-contentful-paint-issue-in-next-js-image/78039837#78039837)

Comment: using priority row is giving another issue. it needs to be given high priority.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some possible solutions you can try:

1. The image dimensions you provided are quite large (748x500 pixels), which means the browser needs to download a significant amount of data to render it. You can opt for smaller-resolution images for the mobile device, which might help.
2. While using `srcset`, downloading and using huge files causes significant performance hits, especially on mobile devices on mobile networks. Just be sure it is not something that's causing problems here. Also, have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4421) which might give you more idea about this.

Comment: Cannot reduce image quality. Client requirement. Is there any other way where i can achieve this scenario without reducing image size?